# convert place name to coordinates by geopy

Tags: python, pandas, geopy

My script is as below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim


def getLocationByGeo(cityname):

     try:
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='my-application')
        location = geolocator.geocode(cityname)
        lat = location.latitude
        lng = location.longitude
        return (lat,lng)
    except:
        # except unrecoginisable address
        pass
```

when I run this file, I can successfully get coordinates.

```
Copenhagen  (55.6867243, 12.5700724)
Dublin  (53.3497645, -6.2602732)
Dubrovnik   (42.6499638, 18.0936953)
Dulles international    (38.9522097, -77.4534242937754)
Edinburgh   (55.9521476, -3.1889908)
```

But when run another file，I cannot get the coordinates.

```
Gatwick
Heathrow
Heathrow Airport
Heathrow T5
Hotel
Kings Cross
London Kings Cross
Copenhagen
```

I am so confused that, like in the first file, I can get for example 'Copenhagen' coordinates, while in the second file I use the sample code, but even cannot 'Copenhagen' coordinates?

Comment: The exceptions you ignore in the `except` block would probably shed some light into what's happening.

Comment: Try printing the Exception as e. There's a similar tutorial here: https://medium.com/python-in-plain-english/how-to-use-geocoding-libraries-to-visualise-pakistans-conflict-data-f16b4a52853c